# How to plot coordinates with a slider for the time in R?

Tags: r, slider, scatter-plot

Here is an example of my dataframe in R:

```
time                      Coordinate.x   Coordinate.y
2015-11-15T23:59:55.711   161569.8       383030.9
2015-11-15T23:59:55.717   161569.9       383031.0
2015-11-15T23:59:55.723   161569.9       383031.0
2015-11-15T23:59:55.730   161570.0       383031.0
2015-11-15T23:59:55.763   161570.0       383031.0
2015-11-15T23:59:55.804   161570.0       383031.0
```

I already made a scatterplot for the x and y coordinates, but now I want to add a slider for the time, I want to slide it for each second so you only see a few coordinates at once.
I can't figure out how to add the slider, can someone help me?

Comment: Interactivity means that you want to build an application, not just draw a plot.  For that you need R-Shiny. Bad news - it's a whole new framework to learn. Good news - I think stock examples there have something very similar to what you need, so only minor adjustments will be required.

Comment: Have a look at the package `ggvis`

Comment: Ah thanks, already thought that wouldn't be possible with a plot..  I will look into Shiny and ggvis